# TypeScript inferencing with process.exit

Tags: typescript

Normally, TypeScript can infer the type of a variable with the help of a guard follow by a return:

```js
type Pet = Dog | Cat;
function isDog(pet: Pet): pet is Dog {
  return true;
}

function fn1(pet: Pet) {
  if (isDog(pet)) {
    return;
  }

  // At this point, TS knows that `pet` is a `Cat`.
}
```

However, if I were to change the return to `process.exit`, this does not work anymore:

```js
function fn2(pet: Pet) {
  if (isDog(pet)) {
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // At this point, we know that `pet` should be a `Cat`, but TS doesn't know.
}
```

Is there a way for me to signal to the compiler that the program would have ended after `process.exit`, in a similar fashion as `return`?

Of course, I could just add a return after `process.exit`. However, in my actual code, my function is returning something, call it `MyObject`, such that there is no reasonable value for when `pet` is a `Dog`, hence the forceful exit.

I am aware that I could do some type assertions to get around this, but wondering what is a good way to solve this.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it's a limitation of Typescript (even the latest version).

Workaround:

You can `return process.exit(1)`.

```
type Pet = Dog | Cat

function isDog(pet: Pet): pet is Dog {
    return true
}

function fn1(pet: Pet) {
    if (isDog(pet)) {
        return process.exit(1)
    }

    return console.log(pet)
}
```

Typescript infers `pet` to be a `Cat`.

[image: screenshot of code]

Answer (score 3):

It's a design limitation of TypeScript and there is no intention of fixing it. It wouldn't know that `process.exit()` causes the process to exit, in the same way as if you use a function that always throws an exception, it wouldn't know that either. Even if your function returns `never`.

Quote from maintainers:

> Reachability in your example is determined by type, but the graph is built syntactically.

As a nicer workaround, you could write:

```
return process.exit(0);
```

Similar issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8655

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon this question in 2021 and the current answers are out-of-date.

[As of TypeScript 3.7](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28859#issuecomment-549111838), any statement that returns `never` will assert that the lines under it will be marked as unreachable.
[source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28859)

This is how `process.exit` is typed in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a0df94d0eb4fcd55e4f0a009a25ee9078da7e4f3/types/node/process.d.ts#L584).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Rico Kahler's answer, you can also wrap process.exit with a function returning never:

```
function abort(message: string): never {
    console.error(message)
    process.exit(1)
}

const x = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 42 : 'string'
if (typeof x === 'number') abort('we got a bad flip')
const y = x.toLowerCase()
```